# How to find a string in List of list of string

Tags: apex

I have an output, which contains List< List< string>>. I want to find a particular string in list.

Current output is

```
((TAUX1, EUR, VEC482_ALGE, 2.0), (TAUX1, EUR, VEC502_ALGE, 2.0), (TAUX1, EUR, VEC481_ALGE, 2.0), (TAUX1, EUR, VEC501_ALGE, 2.0), (TAUX1, EUR, VEC503_ALGE, 2.0), (PVCHT, DZD, VEC482_ALGE, 1738461.54), (PVCHT, DZD, VEC502_ALGE, 1924786.32), (PVCHT, DZD, VEC481_ALGE, 1541880.34), (PVCHT, DZD, VEC501_ALGE, 1667521.37), (PVCHT, DZD, VEC503_ALGE, 2039316.24),(PVHART, EUR, VEC482_ALGE, 4.0),(PVHART, EUR, VEC482_ALGE, 4.0),(PVHART, EUR, VEC482_ALGE, 4.0) ...)
```

Expected final output, which contains "PVCHT"

```
((PVCHT, DZD, VEC502_ALGE, 1924786.32), (PVCHT, DZD, VEC481_ALGE, 1541880.34), (PVCHT, DZD, VEC501_ALGE, 1667521.37), (PVCHT, DZD, VEC503_ALGE, 2039316.24))
```

Comment: Just iterate over your output and filter the results.

Comment: are you always looking for a match on the 0th element of the inner list of strings?

Comment: yes.i am looking for the match on the 0th element of the inner list of string

Comment: Why down vote guys? it seems valid question from beginner stand point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the rows and check for the first column value with the filter condition.

Row: The outer List which contains lists as its elements.
Column: Each element in the inner list.

Code:

```
List<List<String>> input; //your input double dimension list
List<List<String>> result = new List<List<String>>();
for(List<String> column: input)
{
  if(null != column && column.size()>0 && 'PVCHT' == column[0])
  {
    result.add(column);
  }
}
System.debug(result);
```

Comment: Usually answers are more effective if they are more than pure code. A little explanation goes a long way.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I understand that but here I felt its not required. Anyways I have added some description for better understanding. Thank you.

Comment: its working fine for me,thank you very much.as a beginner its help me@ Saumya Ranjan Satapath